# android: How to draw on a canvas of a view from another customized class?

Tags: android, canvas, view

I will be very grateful is somebody can help.

I have created a grid of views with a TableLayout in my xml file.
In the corresponding java file, I retrieve the id of all views in an array view.
I have another class which receive in its constructor a reference to an above created view, in order to draw on its canvas.

```
public class Mosaique extends Activity {

Box [][]box = new Box[NL][NC];

View [][] boxMosaique = new View[NL][NC];
//...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mosaique);

    boxMosaique[0][0] = findViewById(R.id.b_00);
    boxMosaique[0][1] = findViewById(R.id.b_01);
    boxMosaique[0][2] = findViewById(R.id.b_02);
//…
for (int lig=0;lig<NL;lig++)
        for(int col=0;col<NC;col++)
          box[lig][col] = new Box(boxMosaique[lig][col], bckgrnd_color, lig,col);
}
//...
}
// The constructor of the another class which access the views for drawing

public Box(View aView, int backGroundColor, int lig, int col){

    this.aView = aView;
    this.lig = lig;
    this.col = col;
    this.backGroundColor = backGroundColor;
// How to access the canvas of aView for drawing  ?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing Box class as View.

```
Box extends View{
float lig;
float col;
Clolr backGroundColor;

...

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
//draw here on canvas
...
}

public drawBox(int backGroundColor, int lig, int col){

    this.aView = aView;
    this.lig = lig;
    this.col = col;
    this.backGroundColor = backGroundColor;
    invalidate()
}
```

instead of adding constructors, add a method to set box values and call invalidate() once the values are set.

Comment: Thaks Mr Rao. How can I then call the constructor of a box object from the function protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) using findViewById(...)?

Comment: Box boxView = findviewById(..); boxview.drawBox(...); this will draw the box since it internally calls invalldate()-which basically insturtucts to redraw the view.